# How to use “jstat”

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

> jstat[option vmid[interval[s|ms][count]]]

i input jstat -gc 12285 get 12285 not found

so, why? and how to fix it?

> 1. ps -ef|grep "java" 
>      tomcat   12285     1  4 Jul15 ?        03:14:42 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Xmn512m -Xss256k -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.port=8044 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/tomcat_gc.log -javaagent:/usr/local/tomcat/extend/skywalking-agent/skywalking-agent.jar -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
>      root     36537 35893  0 11:29 pts/0    00:00:00 grep java

so, the vmid is 12285

> 2.but jstat -gc 12285 get "12285 not found"

I expect the output of the java JVM's heap status, including Eden, survivor, Old, Permian's status, and GCtime information

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe a permission thing? That process is owned by the "tomcat" user. Try running the jstack as that user (via su or whatever).

Comment: it works! that is the reason!

Comment: Awesome! If you want, you can self-answer this to get some stack overflow points :)